# Why can I use external non static classes and methods inside main, and can't with classes and methods defined inside the class?

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

I naturally can *have* classes inside any class, so in my *`main`* method. I also can access to its methods and its attributes.

But this code isn't working. I know main to be **`static`**, so is it something like:

***The main method runs and is it the one constructing any class, even the one who contains it.***

Then, main should start, construct the class who contains it, and then any class or method inside.

```
package holamundo;


public class HolaMundo {


    public class AnotherClass {

        // Class body
    }

    public void method () {

        // Code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
        method();
    }
```

So doing:

```
package holamundo;


public class HolaMundo {


    public static class AnotherClass {

        // Class body
    }

    public static void method () {

        // Code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
        method();
    }
```

We could say main is running first, among the `AnotherClass` and `method` definitions?

Comment: A [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) might help.

Comment: A non `static` inner class is the same as a non `static` field (in concept), they rely on an instance of the parent class in order to have any meaning.  You might find reading through [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of some help

Comment: @MadProgrammer 'Non-static inner class' is an oxymoron. A non-static nested class *is* an inner class by definition.

Comment: As I understand it, a "nested class" describes a inner, anonymous and local class...(based how I read the tutorials) and as I understand what the OP is asking, he's specify asking about inner classes, since they can be declared as both `static` and non-`static`...or am I misunderstanding your comment...this is why I didn't make it an answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried writing this up with my own words, but the SCJP 6 book does it way better, so here it goes:

> A static nested class is simply a class that's a static member of the
>   enclosing class

Perhaps to better understand, here's some code:

```
  public class HolaMundo {

    public static class AnotherClass {

       public void hello(){
           System.out.println("Hello");
       }

       public static void hola(){
           System.out.println("Hola");
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HolaMundo.AnotherClass.hola();

        HolaMundo.AnotherClass holaAnother = new HolaMundo.AnotherClass();
        holaAnother.hello();

    }
}
```

Note that the above code in the `main()` method will continue to work if you remove the occurrences of `HolaMundo.`.

If you're confused, here's more from the book:

> The class itself isn't really "static"; there's no such thing as a
>   static class. The static modifier in this case says that the nested
>   class is a static member of the outer class. That means it can be
>   accessed, as with other static members, without having an instance of
>   the outer class.

A `static` method (like `main()`), doesn't belong (**and also cannot access**) to any particular instance of any class.
This means that a static method can create new instances of any class it has access to, even if it happens to be an instance of the class that declared said method in the first place.

Now, since in this case, `main()`, `AnotherClass` and `method()` are all static members of `HolaMundo`, then yes, this means that they all "run together".
More specifically, they are loaded when the class is first loaded by the JVM (aka at Class Loading time).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, non-static nested classes have an implicit reference to an instance of the container class and so cannot be utilized in static contexts (like the main method) since there is no instance to reference.